# What does this quotient space look like?

Tags: general-topology

I could not find a complete solution for the next problem:

Let $A \sim B \iff A = PBP^{-1}$ be the equivalence relation for  $M_2(R)$
matrices. Here $P$ is an invertible matrix.

Describe the quotient set $X/\!\sim$ and the quotient space?  Here $X = \left\lbrace \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix} \right\rbrace$.

Could someone help, please?

I tried to check the trivial case: is this quotient topology discrete? The answer is - No. Counterexample: $$
A_0 = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
B_0 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
\lambda_{1,2} = \left\lbrace1,0\right\rbrace
$$

Comment: For each equivalence class you can choose a representative that is in Jordan canonical form. The $2\times 2$ Jordan canonical forms are either diagonal matrices or matrices with the same number in the diagonal and a one in the upper right corner.

Comment: @orole: thank you for your respond. I need a topological solution. How this quotient space looks like?

Comment: You can get it from that. The classes of all diagonalizable matrices form a $\mathbb{C^2}$. (By the way, the representatives above are in the case that the field is the complex numbers. For the reals you have [other representatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices).) The non-diagonalizable matrices form a $\mathbb{C}$ parametrized by the eigenvalue.

Comment: @orole Actually they are $\mathbb C^2$ modulo swapping the elements.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @Metso Think it is wrong. Need to reconsider, but I haven't had time to get back to it.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: But the idea was right (I mean to use minimal polynomials and tr+det), isn't it?

Comment: I think so, but I was having trouble formalizing the proof. The set was right, but I wasn't sure about the topology on the set.