# What does the quotient space $\operatorname{SL}(n) / \sim$ look like? Is it a quotient manifold?

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, quotient-spaces, linear-groups

First of all, I have never taken a course about Lie algebra or Riemannian manifold, so please be kind about any of my inappropriate way of naming things or giving bad expression.

Suppose $n \in Z^+$, I am considering the space $\operatorname{SL}(n) = \{A \in R^{n \times n}, \operatorname{det} A = 1\}$. A equivalent relationship is defined on $\operatorname{SL}(n)$: $A \sim B$ if and only if there are similar to each other (i.e. there exists matrix $P$, such that $A = PBP^{-1}$.

I am wondering about what does $\operatorname{SL}(n) / \sim$ look like. Is this a quotient manifold?

Remark 1: I don't know about the exact way of describing the topology of $\operatorname{SL}(n)$, but I guess there should be some standard way, as $\operatorname{SL}(n)$ can be considered as an manifold in $R^{n \times n}$ in a natural way.

Remark 2: I have found some discussion (like [What does this quotient space look like?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2640319/what-does-this-quotient-space-look-like)), which considers a very similar problem but with the manifold $M_n(R)$ instead. In this case the quotient space might not even be Hausdorff. So I wonder the answer for the case where we exclude those bad(i.e. not invertible) matrices.

Remark 3: I'm not sure about the answer. On one hand the intuition tells me that the quotient space should be a manifold, because we already have excluded bad things; on the other hand, I think the answer is no because it seems to relate to the multiplicity of the eigenvalues.

Comment: I suspect that the space will have singularities (i.e. fail to be a manifold) at points corresponding to matrices $A$ such that $C_A = \{P: AP = PA\}$ is unusually large. For "most" matrices, $C_A$ is an $n$-dimensional subspace, but $C_A$ becomes larger, for example, when $A$ is diagonalizable with repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am worried about in the Remark 3: When A has repeated eigenvalues, $C_A$ can be a nontrivial set. But I'm not sure what does this imply with respect to the manifold property. I know a concept named "free" group action, but the action $A \to PAP^{-1}$ can no way be free.

Comment: It is also non-Hausdorff. The "right" thing to do is to use a "Mumford" or "GIT" quotient. I think I wrote an answer to a similar question earlier, I will try to find it.

Comment: @EggTart Intuitively, what comes to mind is [this kind of result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/98653/81360). The local dimension of the quotient space depends on the dimension of the stabilizer subgroup. If the stabilizer dimension is point dependent then the space does not have a constant dimension and so fails to be a manifold

Comment: Yes, as others have commented/insinuated, the behavior near repeated eigenvalues ... including proper Jordan blocks... illustrates the non-manifold/non-Hausdorff-ness, etc. Also, you might just want to refer to "conjugacy classes", rather than "similarly classes": the former is far more standard than the latter, by this year, I think.

Comment: Is there a way we can define a "local quotient manifold" structure, when the matrix does not suffer from the repeated eigenvalues?